# View based table creation for I-Pad

Tags: ipad

I am creating table using UIView on I-Pad but the problem is it creates for one column with multiple rows and I want table composed of multiple rows with multiple columns. Could anyone please suggest me some ideas anything that will work to solve this problem.

Comment: you cannot create columns in using single UITableView object.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few open source grid view controls around.  Try:

- [AQGridView](http://quatermain.tumblr.com/post/528737778/aqgridview-lives-for-my-ipad-dev-camp-hackathon)
- [DTGridView](http://danieltull.co.uk/blog/2009/10/28/dtgridview/)